# Counter showed 50Hz when I put it across my body. Why?

Tags: frequency, counter

I was messing with my new counter when I connected it to fingers and it showed 50Hz (the AC frequency in my country.)

Why?

Answer (score 4):

Because your body acts like the plate of a capacitor and picks up residual electric fields from the AC wiring in your house and, the meter detects these as 50 Hz.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the electric fields around you, all the electrical lines in your house for example exhibit their electric fields along the wires and your body can perceive them and act like an antenna; that's why when you touch a conductor you can transmit these electric fields into that conductor. Same way when you touch an antenna of an analog TV, you somehow improve the reception of the TV because your body becomes an extension of the antenna and thus pick up more electric fields in the air.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't surprising if you holding the oscilloscope probe you can see in the same effect that 50 or 60 hertz depending on the country will be more evident on the scope.

The reason for this is that AC can travel through the air it's pretty much a radio wave although the lower frequencies may have more magnetic or electric components